# dump hash values to yaml file sequentially in perl

Tags: perl

I want to dump the content of hash sequentially in to the yaml file, i dont want it to be printed in alphabetical manner.

```
#!usr/bin/perl
use strict;
use warnings;
use YAML qw(Dump);

my $hash = { b => "2", a => "1", d => "4", c => "3" };
open( FH, ">file.yaml" ) or die "Can't open file.yaml : $!\n";
print FH Dump($hash);
close FH;
```

Expected output is

```
---
b:2
a:1
d:4
c:3
```

but i got output as

```
---
a:1
b:2
c:3
d:4
```

Answer (score 5):

Perl plain hashes are not ordered, and [`YAML`](https://metacpan.org/pod/distribution/YAML/lib/YAML.pod) module sorts the keys by default.

However, `YAML` provides `Bless` function so you can alter the behavior for how data structures are output.  For Hashes, this lets you specify both the specific keys you want output along with their order:

```
use strict;
use warnings;
use YAML qw(Dump Bless);

my $hash = { b => "2", a => "1", d => "4", c => "3" };

Bless($hash)->keys( [qw(b a d c)] );
print Dump($hash);
```

output

```
b: 2
a: 1
d: 4
c: 3
```

Note that Blessing a Perl data structure does not change it anyway. The extra information is stored separately and looked up by the Blessed node's memory address.